# Magento 2 with Yii2

Tags: yii2, magento2

We need to Login and signup from magento 2 (signup and login form) to yii2 in website. Yii2 is installed in root directory and magento 2 is installed in shop directory.
Please let us know in case anyone has any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Calling A.P.I. magento inside yii and use it.

in index.php

```
require_once('app/Mage.php');//Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();
```

Then

```
if(!Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()){
        //not logged in
}else{
        // logged in
}
```

Plus minus this is the way, then do your test